# Platform/Location Independent ini file

Tags: java

I have a Java application I have to optimise, and is almost complete. This application must run on all platforms, no matter the location. On windows in particular, the application is run via CMD.

The application works with MySQL Databases and pulls the URL, username and password from an ini file.

How can I read from this file, no matter the OS and no matter the location of the application?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It would help to see the file..

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisSavard
JDBC_Driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
DB_URL=<hidden for privacy>
USER=root
PASS=arkenstone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After doing some digging, I found this solution:

```
System.getProperty("user.dir/bin/config.ini");
System.getProperty(key, args);
```

This will use the current working directory at runtime and search for the "bin" folder, and then the config.ini file. This is multi-platform and directory independent, providing the file name does not change, and the file remains where it is.

You can use the System.getProperty(s) methods in the same way as you would a Properties object.

Answer (score 0):

I use this code;

```
static  protected   synchronized void   initialiseProperties() {
    debugMsg("Initialising properties...");
    try {
        dbProp = new Properties();
        dbProp.load(DBProperties.class.getResourceAsStream(DB_PROPS));
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        debugMsg("Exception loading properties file.");
        dbProp = null;
    }
}
```

Then put the properties in the jar file.

Comment: Also a great idea, is there any way you can think of that will let me just change a file without un-packing a jar, changing properties then re-packing the jar?

Comment: Not really, unless your code is running in an Application Server, such as WebSphere, in which case you can use a URI reference in your java code, and map this to a real file at deployment time.